# Did the ancient Greeks have "taverns"?

Tags: ancient-greece, social-history

Context: I am going to be starting a D&D campaign in a world based on ancient Greece, rather than your classic western european medieval fantasy land. This will probably not be the only question regarding everyday life in that place and period, as I am no historian.

If a band of regular folk are travelling throughout the ancient Greek countryside and they happen upon a village where they decide to stay for the night, where could they stay for the night? Would they be able to find a room to rent for the night, food and drink aplenty and local to gossip with?

If so, what typical food would they be able to find there? What would have made up the carbs in your everyday meal back then? Was there meat every day? What would they have washed it down with?

Comment: Googling 'ancient Greece tavern' gives these 1st page links which seem to have what you are looking for: Wikipedia's [Taverna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History) and [Tavernas in ancient Greece c. 475-146 BC: an archaeological perspective](https://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/assemblage/html/6/Kelly_web.html). Also, see Wikipedia's [Ancient Greek cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_cuisine).

Comment: @LarsBosteen Maybe worth also voting to close when questions are off-topic as *too-basic**?

Answer (score 1):

**Taverna**

[History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History)

> The earliest evidence of a Greek restaurant, or taverna, was discovered at the Ancient Agora of Athens (or Athenian Agora) during archaeological excavations conducted by the American School of Classical Studies in the early 1970s.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History) Large quantities of classical Greek cooking and eating utensils were found at the taverna such as plates, mixing bowls, lidded casseroles, spits for broiling meat, mortars for chopping and grinding, as well as a cooking bell and a variety of jugs.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History) Furthermore, large amounts of fish bones and shellfish remains were discovered revealing the menu specialties of the classical Greek taverna such as oysters, mussels, murex shells, and large fish.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History) A nearby wine shop in the Athenian Agora, possibly in association with the taverna, served local Attic wine, as well as a wide variety of wines imported from Chios, Mende, Corinth, Samos and Lesbos.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taverna#History)